# jquery animate images

Tags: jquery

I have list of images. Is it possible to have all the ads randomly rotate in and out of those spots every 5 seconds

```
<div id="s1" class="pics">

<img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200">
<img src="http://placekitten.com/150/150">
<img src="http://placekitten.com/180/180">
<img src="http://placekitten.com/170/170">
<img src="http://placekitten.com/140/140">
<img src="http://placekitten.com/160/160">

</div>


$(document).ready(function(){

    var numberOfImages;
    $(".pics img").each(function(){
        numberOfImages = $(".pics img").size();
        //alert(numberOfImages);
    });


});
```

Really not sure how to do this. can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Wait...do you want to replace a random image with a pre-defined ad? Or do you want to replace a single image with one of a variety of other images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would store the image sources in an array and then iterate over the array. Something like this:

```
var myImages = [
    "http://placekitten.com/200/200",
    "http://placekitten.com/150/150",
    "http://placekitten.com/180/180",
    "http://placekitten.com/170/170",
    "http://placekitten.com/140/150",
    "http://placekitten.com/160/160"
];
var counter = 1;  // Start at number 2 since the HTML tag has the first

function switchImage() {
    $('#myImage').attr('src', myImages[counter]);
    counter += 1;

    if (counter == myImages.length) {
        counter = 0;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(switchImage, 5000);
});
```

Then, in your HTML:

```
 <img id='myImage' src='http://placekitten.com/200/200' />
```

Or you could just search Google for "jQuery cycle". Personally, I like the [Nivo Slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [jQuery Cycle Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/). It has a `random` option that does exactly what you describe.